# Ansible service restart does not work

Tags: docker, nginx, service, vagrant, ansible

I use Ansible in order to provision a Docker container with Vagrant.

My Ansible file contains the following section to start nginx:

```
- name: nginx started
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: restarted
```

From what I understand, this section should restart nginx in all cases, but when I connect via SSH to the container, `nginx` is not running (the whole Ansible provision process succeeds, there is no log for nginx in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`). It starts correctly when I manually type the following command: `sudo service nginx start`.

However, it works when I replace the section above by:

```
- name: nginx restarted
  command: service nginx restart
```

It seems the issue is not limited to `nginx`, and also happens with other services like `syslog-ng`.

Any idea why using Ansible `service` does not work ? (docker 17.10.0, Vagrant 2.0.1, Ansible 2.4.0)

Comment: What's the Docker image your container is run from?

Comment: @zigarn My container is based on this image: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker (phusion/baseimage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible `service` module [try to guess the underlying init system](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.2.0-1/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py#L433).
In your case of the [`phusion/baseimage`](https://hub.docker.com/r/phusion/baseimage/) docker image, [it finds `/sbin/initctl`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.2.0-1/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py#L479), so the module simply launch `/sbin/initctl stop nginx; /sbin/initctl start nginx` inside the container which [does nothing](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/06e2983ba995c2e5684f8414b861425c7f5e6369/image/prepare.sh#L20) as the init system is changed in this image ([`my_init`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init)).

So the problem is the inconsistent init system state of the image that ansible doesn't detect correctly.

The solutions are:

- write a `my_init` ansible module (service module try first to use the `{{ ansible_service_mgr }}` module [[code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.2.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/action/service.py#L40)])
- remove `initctl` from the image, so ansible will not detect any init system and will use the `service` command (maybe raise an issue in [phusion/baseimage-docker](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker))
- use the `command` module to explicitly use `service` command as you finally did

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into [this ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9108) I think it may be related.

According to them:

> ...this is not service specific. The restarted/reloaded options are
>   currently simple options that call the underlying init systems
>   scripts, which (if successful) return success...

So, probably that's why even in [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/service_module.html) you can find an example of what you were trying to achieve:

```
# Example action to restart service httpd, in all cases
- service:
    name: httpd
    state: restarted
```

But for **nginx** doesn't work as it may not be supported.

Appart from your solution:

```
- name: nginx restarted
  command: service nginx restart
```

You can achieve that by using:

```
- name: restart nginx
  service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, this is definitely the same issue. Concerning the last example you gave me, why would it work better than the first solution I have tried ? Only the syntax is different, right ?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it as another approach, both should work.

Comment: Hmmm... I've just checked again and neither of these two solutions work. The only solution that works is the one using `command`. I have also tried with `stopped` and `started` as mentioned into the Ansible Github issue. Anyway, I'm gonna keep the first solution for now. As you said, nginx may not be supported. Thanks.